# Calculating Tor for an R[t]-module

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity. Let $M$ be a finitely generated $R[t]$-module with a projective resolution $$ 0 \longrightarrow P \longrightarrow Q \longrightarrow M \longrightarrow 0 $$ where $P$, $Q$ are finitely generated projective $R[t]$-modules.

Now it is given that $M$ is killed by some power of $t$, let's say $t^n$ kills $M$.

To show that $\mathrm{Tor}^{R[t]}_{1}(M,R[t]/(t^n))$ is $M$ itself.

My attempt:

Given a short exact sequence I always have a long exact sequence of $\mathrm{Tor}$, thus I have $$0\longrightarrow \mathrm{Tor}^{R[t]}_{1}(M,R[t]/(t^n)) \longrightarrow P \otimes R[t]/(t^n) \longrightarrow Q \otimes R[t]/(t^n) \longrightarrow M \otimes R[t]/(t^n)  \longrightarrow 0.$$
Now for any $R[t]$-module $N$ we have $N \otimes R[t]/(t^n) \cong N/t^nN$.

So I know that $\mathrm{Tor}^{R[t]}_{1}(M,R[t]/(t^n))$ is nothing but the kernel of $$P/t^nP \longrightarrow Q/t^nQ.$$

Here I have some trouble in calculating the kernel and showing it is isomorphic to $M$.

I think the isomorphism can be shown from here as well but it seems I am missing something very obvious
$$0\longrightarrow \mathrm{Tor}^{R[t]}_{1}(M,R[t]/(t^n)) \longrightarrow P/t^nP \longrightarrow P /t^nQ \longrightarrow 0$$

For any help or hint I am grateful.

Comment: When you have a projective resolution of $A$, the easiest way to compute $\operatorname{Tor}_\bullet(A, B)$ is to tensor the deleted resolution with $B$ and take homology!

Comment: Yes absolutely, then again if I am doing that I need to find the above mentioned kernel is it not?

Comment: Your last sequence isn't exact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One has the exact sequence
$$0\to t^n R[t]\to R[t]\to R[t]/t^n R[t]\to0.$$
Tensoring with $M$ gives a long exact sequence
$$\cdots\to\text{Tor}_1^{R[t]}(M,R[t])
\to\text{Tor}_1^{R[t]}(M,R[t]/t^n R[t])\to M\otimes_{R[t]}t^n R[t[\to M\otimes_{R[t]}R[t]\to\cdots.
$$
Since $R[t]$ is projective, $\text{Tor}_1^{R[t]}(M,R[t])=0$ and this
reduces to
$$\cdots\to0
\to\text{Tor}_1^{R[t]}(M,R[t]/t^n R[t])\to M\stackrel{\times t^n}\longrightarrow M\to\cdots$$
which gives $\text{Tor}_1^{R[t]}(M,R[t]/t^n R[t])$ as the $t^n$-torsion of $M$.

Under your hypotheses, that is all of $M$.

Comment: Oh right instead of going through projective resolution of M I could have just used the balancing of Tor just like this. Thank you.

Comment: $t^nR[t]$ is free of rank $1$ (here is is important that $t^n$ is not a zero divisor) and so $M\otimes t^n R[t]\cong M$, via $m\otimes t^n\mapsto m$. This element is mapped to $t^nm\in M\cong M\otimes R[t]$.